# How to access System.getProperty() in Java Sample of Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
public class Jmetertest extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {    

   public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {    
     TestConfig.load(System.getProperty("configFile"));
      // This configFile has all the properties which I need to run my test
     }
   public void teardownTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {..}
   public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {    
    // test code
   }
}
```

I am aware of the fact that I can use,

```
public Arguments getDefaultParameters() {..}
```

But I want to know, how can I access `System.getProperty();` in jmeter so I can use whatever is more convenient for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

```
public void setUp()
 {
     testFile1 = 
         new File(
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/testfiles",
```

and i think this link can help you :
[java.lang.System.getProperty](http://www.jexamples.com/srchRes/java.lang.System.getProperty?chunk=70)